# Как сделать чтобы при нажатии страница не возвращалась вверх

Tags: html, css

Есть выплывающий текст:

```html
<div id="cat">
  <h4><a href="#" class="disabled" style="color:#737373; text-decoration:none">Вопрос?</a></h4>
        <p style="margin-top:10px;">
<em>Ответ</em>
        </p>
</div>
```

При нажатии на "Вопрос" страница поднимается вверх из-за "href="#"". Мне нужно, чтобы страница не поднималась, а оставалась на месте.
Пробовал через стили сделать ссылку некликабельной, работает но тогда пропадает cursor: pointer.

Comment: А если тегу а добавить Id и в href поставить ссылку на него?

Comment: замените решётку на `javascript:`

Comment: @vp_arthспасибо, заработало!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Есть разные способы

**1. Сделать onclick="return false".**

Если функция `onclick` возвращает false то дальнейшая логика обработки ссылок перестаёт выполняться.
Тут может быть любая функция которая возвращает `false`.

```
<a href="#" onclick="return false">link</a>
```

**2. javascript://**

```
<a href="javascript://">link</a>
```

Comment: Спасибо!!!!!!!!

Comment: Пожалуйста.....

Comment: А как сделать upvote? И подскажите, если не трудно, у меня есть <option>Новая Почта (Полная предоплата)</option> и на мобильных устройствах текст вылазит за сам option, не вмещается

Comment: Рядом с ответом стоит число и стрелки верх и вниз, верх это upvote - Ответ полезен.

Answer (score 2):

[event.preventDefault()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) - отменить действие по-умолчанию.

```js
$(function() {
  $('a.disabled').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

```css
#cat {
  margin-top: 1800px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cat">
  <h4><a href="#" class="disabled" style="color:#737373; text-decoration:none">Вопрос?</a></h4>
  <p style="margin-top:10px;">
    <em>Ответ</em>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: попробовал, перестала отображаться страница.

Comment: @ВасилийПупкин где перестала? я в своем примере специально границу дива сделал 1800 пикселей, чтобы прокрутку получить, это пример для показа работающего скрипта. По клику на ссылке вверх прокрутка не идет.

Comment: После того как добавляю <style>
 #cat {
  margin-top: 1800px;
}
</style> перестает работать, на странице вообще пусто

Comment: всё равно кидает вверх...

Comment: @ВасилийПупкин, ответ заключается в `preventDefault`, не нужно копировать себе всё остальное.